# Newtonsoft.json JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I have found many examples of code for JSON.NET, but I am unable to make any of them run in Visual Studio (C#). Quite probably this is because I am missing something obvious in how to code.

Particularly frustrating is the example code in newtonsoft.com will not compile and run. For example http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeObject.htm contains code for 'Types' and 'Usage' but there are no using statements and I can't figure out how to put the code into a project in a way to make it work.

I am sure I am missing something basic I just can't figure it out. I have been Googling for an answer for three days.  Can you help me?

Comment: You haven't given us much to go off of. Have you added a reference to JSON.NET in your project?

Comment: Example code works fine for me? Are you missing a `using Newtonsoft.Json;` statement or the nuget package? https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-dialog

Comment: Could you post the code you've tried ? And maybe a screenshot of your solution explorer (with the `references` node opened)

Comment: On the Json.Net documentation page http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm under API Reference link are listed the namespaces. You'll have to look through them until you find the classes you want to use. The namespace that the class falls under will be the namespace needed in your Using statement.

Comment: I put the example code in to .NET Fiddle, added JSON.Net via nuget (which is how I'd do it in Visual Studio too), added the namespace with a using statement. https://dotnetfiddle.net/gQPEE7 Works fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have downloaded the Json.NET nuget package (or otherwise properly added Newtonsoft's package to your project and referenced it) the only using statement you need other than the standard ones visual studio adds for you is Newtonsoft.Json

Their code runs perfectly fine in a project of type console application with the following using's:

```
    using System;                      
    using System.Collections.Generic; 
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

The only other thing you might want to do is add a Console.ReadLine(); at the end so that you can see the output.

Comment: Oh, also... if you forget to bring in the Newtonsoft.Json namespace to your class, as long as your project has the Newtonsoft library added and referenced you can always put your cursor on the JsonConvert (which would be underlined in red) and press [Ctrl] + [.] (period) and Visual Studio will tell you which namespace you need to add.

Comment: Ryan, I am still completely clueless about how to do this. Can you show me how to read a JSON file and then parse it?  I am just completely lost.  :-(

Comment: Sure, once you bring in the Newtonsoft.Json namespace you will have access to their converter then it's as simple as:

MyObjectType someObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObjectType>(SomeJsonStringRepresentingMyObject);

Answer (score 0):

As I attempted to reply to your questions I created a new C# Console Application Solution named CA_Json.
I right clicked on the project named ‘CA_Json’ and selected ‘Manage NuGet packages…’. 
I then selected ‘Newtonsoft.JSON’ and clicked the ‘Install’ button.
Then this page appeared http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/install?version=8.0.2 and Newtonsoft.JSON appeared under References
So I believe I have added JSON successfully. 
In Program.cs I added this: 
•   using Newtonsoft.Json;
•   the code for Types
•   and the code for Usage
I compiled it and then started debugging and it worked!  
I went back and checked my prior project and somehow the Newtonsoft.JSON Did NOT appear under References, even though I had added it earlier. 
Thanks so much! Your questions forced me to carefully review my work and discover my error. :-)